# Why to multiply all audio input with 1000/sqrt(sumsofInputSquare/datalength)

Tags: sound, data, speech

My thesis is about voice segeration. 
I am reading a code which has been used in this field. It most probably not needed but here is the [fullCode](http://www.cse.ohio-state.edu/pnl/shareware/hu-chapter06/voiced06.zip)

I can't understand something which owner code did ,

```
if ((fp = fopen(filename, "r")) == NULL){
    printf("Cannot open input file!\n");
    exit(0);
}

while (!feof(fp))
{
    float f;
    fscanf(fp, "%f\n", &f);
    Input[SigLength]=f;
    SigLength++;
}
fclose(fp);

float sumE=0;
for(int n=0; n<SigLength; n++)
    sumE += Input[n]*Input[n];

sumE /= float(SigLength);

for(int n=0; n<SigLength; n++)
    Input[n] *= 1000/sqrt(sumE);

return(1000/sqrt(sumE));
```

He opens a file which has DB of sound  like 48, 200 etc..

My question why he is doing the process below ? To apply just logic is common in sound analysis ?

```
for(int n=0; n<SigLength; n++)
    Input[n] *= 1000/sqrt(sumE);
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about electronic design.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companding

Comment: @Leon please tell me which stackexchange site would be more appropriate? I thought because it is part of DSP project, this place would be best.

Comment: Looks like they are calculating and multibying by [RMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Root_mean_square) (root mean square)

Comment: @jippie yes , I am tring to understand why. Ignacio's answer seems logical .

Comment: Just as an aside, the [Signal Processing StackExchange](http://dsp.stackexchange.com/) might be of interest.

Comment: @AnindoGhosh I think you are right I didn't know it before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This normalizes the RMS power of the data set, per unit time, but based on a measurement over the entire data set rather than the periodic or sliding type of power measurement used by a continuous AGC.